# SQL Server 2016 & Python 3.6.4 Data Entry Error

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am currently working on automating data entry for a few look up tables in a SQL Server 2016 database. I am fairly new to SQL in general however have a few years of experience in Python. My issue is that if I don't have a value for each column in one of the tables that I am inserting data into, it throws the following error message at me.

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Implicit conversion from data type smalldatetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. (257) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')
```

Now to explain.
I am extracting data from an excel file and dumping/altering them into a tuple for each row (Shown below).

#### Python print output

```
Extracting data from AE60 to AJ66
('Item 1', 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 11, 14, 48, 733561), 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 11, 14, 48, 733561), 1)
('Item 2', 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 11, 14, 48, 733561), 1, None, None)
('Item 3', 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 11, 14, 48, 733561), 1, None, None)
('Item 4', 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 11, 14, 48, 733561), 1, None, None)
('Item 5', 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 11, 14, 48, 733561), 1, None, None)
('Item 6', 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 11, 14, 48, 733561), 1, None, None)
('Item 7', 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 11, 14, 48, 733561), 1, None, None)
INSERT INTO product.ProductFamily VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

Now to go along with this, I am inserting these into the database via the following line.

#### pyodbc cursor.execute()

```
cursor.execute(finstr, args)
```

Where **finstr** is the SQL code in the last line of the Python print output and **args** is any one of the tuples above the SQL code.

Now if I were to insert the first tuple, which has a value for each column (i.e. no **None**'s), then I get no errors and everything is fine. However, if I were to insert any of the other 6 tuples below that, which have a **None** value, I get the error stated above. The SQL code for the table in question is shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE product.ProductFamily 
( ProductFamilyID  int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  FamilyName  varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  Active bit NOT NULL, 
  DateCreated datetime NOT NULL,
  CreatedBy int NOT NULL,
  DateModified datetime,
  ModifiedBy int
)
```

We can see that the last two columns are able to be null as they are set that way by default, and I have read that Python's **None** type is translated to **null** over pyodbc. There is also no instance of a "smalldatetime" field anywhere so this issue is quite confusing.

Comment: Try using a fieldlist in your insert statement to confirm that the data elements are associated correctly, e.g. `INSERT INTO product.ProductFamily (FamilyName, Active, DateCreated, CreatedBy, DateModified, ModifiedBy) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);` Also, as a doublecheck, dump your 'Args' and ensure that nothing random has happened to the order of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either specifying the column list in INSERT *or* using the correct ODBC driver will fix this.  The "SQL Server" driver that comes with Windows is very old.

Here's a repro:

```
import csv
import datetime
import pyodbc

#sql_connection = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=tempdb;Trusted_Connection=YES'

sql_connection = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=(local);Database=tempdb;Trusted_Connection=YES'

connection = pyodbc.connect(sql_connection, autocommit=True)

connection.execute("if not exists (select * from sys.schemas where name = 'production') exec('create schema production') ")

connection.execute('drop table if exists production.ProductFamily')

sql = """
CREATE TABLE production.ProductFamily 
( ProductFamilyID  int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  FamilyName  varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  Active bit NOT NULL, 
  DateCreated datetime NOT NULL,
  CreatedBy int NOT NULL,
  DateModified datetime,
  ModifiedBy int
)  """


connection.execute(sql)

sql = 'INSERT INTO production.ProductFamily(FamilyName,Active,DateCreated,CreatedBy,DateModified,ModifiedBy) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);'
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql,'Item 1', 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 11, 14, 48, 733561), 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 11, 14, 48, 733561), 1)
cursor.execute(sql,'Item 2', 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 11, 14, 48, 733561), 1, None, None)

print('done')
```

Comment: Thanks, changing the driver worked perfectly, can't believe that was the only issue!